# writing wav file on node server from formdata

Tags: node.js, express, audio, multer

I want to save wav file locally on node server after receiving formData from client-side.
But the wav file created sounds broken(it only plays noise).

Im using react-media-recorder-2 to record audio for client-side app (React).
On the server, I console log buffer and there are bytes

I'm stuck, can someone help me please..

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const cors = require("cors");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const wavEncoder = require("wav-encoder");

const app = express();
const port = 3002;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// Configure Multer to handle file uploads in memory
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/api/audioToText", upload.any(), async (req, res) => {
  const AUDIO_FILE_NAME = "receivedAudio";

  try {
    if (!req.files) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ success: false, message: "No audio file received." });
    }

    const buffer = req.files[0].buffer;
    const sampleRate = 44100;

    // Convert the received audio to WAV format
    const wavBuffer = await wavEncoder.encode({
      sampleRate: sampleRate,
      channelData: [new Float32Array(buffer)],
    });

    // Save the WAV file to the server
    const wavFilePath = path.join(
      __dirname,
      `./audioFile/${AUDIO_FILE_NAME}.wav`,
    );
    fs.writeFileSync(wavFilePath, Buffer.from(wavBuffer));

    // Send a success response to the client
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: "Audio received and saved successfully.",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing audio:", error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ success: false, message: "Error processing audio." });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```